# Is there a way to easily see if dispatch of Azure/Microsoft Graph webhooks is having an issue?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-eventgrid

**Update:** Issue solved! Webhooks are now working again.
As such the question changes to: *Is there a way to easily see if Azure/Microsoft Graph is having an issue?*

**Yesterday's Story**
After creating a whole chain of events to be triggered by a subscription to changes in Office365 Calendar events, the events stopped rolling in. Creating a new subscription would still yield a request to validate our endpoint; however no actual events were received.

We verified that we were indeed creating subscriptions, following up by manually creating them using Microsoft's [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to rule out any issue with our code. We're also able to say with certainty that incoming requests were correctly being logged.

After tweeting to @AzureSupport, we were directed here to create a question they could pass on to "the team".

> **Original Question:**
>   Suddenly, azure graph is no longer sending webhook calls for changes
>   in subscribed graph items.
>
> Thinking this might be a code-problem, rather than an azure problem, I
>   went to Graph Explorer to check it out.
>
> Steps:
>
> - Looked up a calendar id using `GET /me/calendars`
> - Created a (created, updated, deleted) subscription with `POST /subscriptions`
> - NB: this returned a valid response, and also called my endpoint with a validation request as evidenced by server logs
> - Listed events of the subscribed calendar `GET /me/calendars/<id>/events`
> - Fetched a specific event `GET /me/events/<id>`
> - Deleted that event by changing the request method to `DELETE` in the dropdown. Received a `204`.
>
> This all, after having tried similar things with what we're actually
>   building (and editing subscribed events via the `outlook.office.com`
>   web interface)... and as of having typed all of that out, still
>   nothing except validation requests.
>
> Yesterday, it was working as of 17:06:45 UTC and hasn't been as of
>   17:45:09 UTC.
>
> Nothing has changed about how we create/update the webhooks, they've
>   just stopped working.
>
> Is there some kind of limit that would fail silently? (I have been
>   creating/letting expire a lot of webhooks, but only one or two have
>   been active at once)
>
> Ideas? (Besides resorting to polling?) Also Thanks to `@AzureSupport`
>   on Twitter for pointing me here!

So, is there a status endpoint for graph events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about the issues you experienced with Microsoft Graph webhook notifications.

**Here is what happened:**

We experienced a capacity issue that resulted in a delayed deliveries for a subset of notifications. Some subscriptions were affected more than others, with some subscribers seeing a significant drop in notifications delivered. The time period for this issue was between 2AM on 12-12-2018 and 6PM 12-13-2018 (PST).

**What we are going to do:**

1. We are investigating the root cause and will take steps to prevent this from occurring in the future.
2. We recognize that our outage communications for Graph notifications are lacking. We are working on improving our comms with the goal of pro-actively publishing service degradation info to our customers as soon as we realize they occur.

We appreciate your usage of Graph and our webhook notification framework. Sorry about the trouble!

Comment: Did something happen to webhooks again? It looks like all our tenant subscriptions has been deleted at Microsoft, as I can't update them. I've had to create new ones